# 'push ebp' 'pop ebp' not used but still breaks code when removed.

Tags: assembly, x86, arguments

I compiled:

```
"
int x_add(int a, int b)
{
    return a+b;
}
"
```

and got

```
"
push ebp
mov ebp,esp
mov edx,[ebp+08]
mov eax,[ebp+0c]
pop ebp
ret
"
```

I simplified the assembly down to

```
"
mov eax,[esp+0c]
add eax,[esp+08]
ret
"
```

when I run `"x_add(1, 1);"` it returns -1
so I replaced code trying to find out what broke.

```
"
push ebp
mov eax,[esp+0c]
add eax,[esp+08]
pop ebp
ret
"
```

works as expected, returning 1+1=2.
so why does ebp have to be pushed at the beginning then popped at the end if it is never used in the code?

Comment: So.. without that push/pop, did you not notice the value of esp (and thus those offsets used for addressing) is different than with the push/pop, right? You *did*, debug this interactively, right? Short version: `push ebp` modifies `esp`, so if you remove the push/pop, you must adjust your offsets as well.

Comment: yeah a bit new to debuggers. IDA is glitchy and codeblocks skips over the code when I break point it. I am using Cheat engine and didn't think to check the stack pointer.

Comment: If you were to compile the code with optimizations enabled, it would be simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks Cody. I am learning x86 and was about to try that next to see the differences between my optimized code and g++'s output.

Comment: Basically, analyzing debug code (what you get from a compiler with optimizations disabled) is a waste of time. There's a lot of noise, and a lot of stuff that doesn't make sense. It isn't a good way to learn/understand assembly language. [Here's a side-by-side comparison](https://godbolt.org/g/vXMrcP).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is not used it does not need pushing.

In your optimized code, you are using original offsets `0c` and `08` which
were correct when `ebp` is pushed.

You must use `08` and `04` respectively, when you have not pushed anything and `esp` still has its original function-entry value.